# How to Access the 2nd class table

Tags: c#, selenium

```html
<table style="text-align: left; width: 580px;" class="TableText1" border="0">
</table>

<table class="TableText1" nowrap="">
</table>
```

I've used

```
IWebElement baseTable = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("TableText1"[2]));
```

or

```
IWebElement baseTable1 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//table[@class='TableText1'])[position()=2]"));
```

but I found all the data.

I need to access only the 2<sup>nd</sup> class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using index -

```
IWebElement baseTable = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table[@class='TableText1'][2]"));
```

Comment: it access all the data of the content

Comment: @Tamim, Do you mean class name ?

Comment: If you want to get access 2nd tables class name try `string classname = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table[2]")).GetAttribute("class");`

Comment: sry, not access but i hv to get only the table2 data.

Comment: Possibility would be . you have more then 2 tables with same class. so once you do access  by this `//table[@class='TableText1'][2]` It gives you first table . Just change the index to 3 `//table[@class='TableText1'][3]` and try. Also do make sure how many tables you have in your doc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134383/discussion-between-narendra-rajput-and-tamim).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `XPath`:

```
IWebElement baseTable = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("(//table[@class='TableText1'])[2]"));
```

Comment: it access first and second table data

Comment: Try `IWebElement baseTable = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//table[@class='TableText1' and @nowrap]"));`